# Swap two numbers - but only in a particular context

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, conditional

I have a list of terms such as `{2*s[1,2]^2, 3*s[3,5]^4, ...}` and I would like to have a replacement that swaps $2 \leftrightarrow 4, 3 \leftrightarrow 1$, but only within the `s[i,j]` objects. The first guess:

```
In[1]:= {2*s[1,2]^2,3*s[3,5]^4} /. {2:>4, 4:>2, 3:>1, 1:>3}
Out[1]= {4 s[3,4]^4,s[1,5]^2}
```

does not work as it also changes the prefactors and powers. Because of the vast number of elements in the list (and the fact that I can also have more than two arguments, e.g. `s[1,2,3], s[1,2,3,4], ...`), it's impractical to manually code in each `s[1,2]:>s[3,4]` and so on. How would I write a replacement with a condition that it affects numbers only within `s[i,j]`?

Comment: Can `s` have something else than an integer as an argument? E.g. `s[ 1, s[2, a^2] ]`?

Comment: No, it's just numbers like ```s[1,2], s[1,2,3],...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
list = {2*s[1, 2]^2, 3*s[3, 5]^4, g[s[3, 4, 0, 2]]};

list /. expr : s[__] :> (expr /. {
     1 -> 2,
     2 -> 20,
     3 -> 4,
     4 -> 40,
     5 -> 50
     })
```

> `{2 s[2, 20]^2, 3 s[4, 50]^4, g[s[4, 40, 0, 20]]}`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is a slick solution but seems to work:

```
rules = {2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 1} /. {a_ <-> b_ :> {a -> b, b -> a}} // 
   Flatten;
{2*s[1, 2]^2, 3*s[3, 5]^4} /. p : s[_, _] :> (p /. rules)
```